# String excerpts

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I would like to copy a certain string (out of a longer range of strings in one cell) and show it in a different cell with Google Sheets. This is what is in the initial cell A1:A :

```
"String 1","String 2","String 3"
```

In B1:B I'd like ONLY `String 3`, so without the `""` and the other strings.

Is this possible with spreadsheets?
Or is there any other way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

So the task is to get word inside double quotes. And the mathcing string is placed in the end of text.

You may use regular expressions to deal with that, the basic formula is:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"([^""]+)""$")`

This will give a word inside "" from text in cell A1 at the end of text.

For example:

`some text...,"Thisthat","https://www.url.com/de/Thisthat"`
gives `https://www.url.com/de/Thisthat`

You may also use arrayformula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,"([^""]+)""$"))
```

Please, read more about this functions [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625) and [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

---

**Old answer**

if you want strings to be on their rows, use this formula in B1:

`=ArrayFormula(if(A1:A = "String 3";A1:A;""))`

If you have cells in `A1:A`, which contain 'string 3', and you want to match them too, use this:

`=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(A1:A , "String 3"),"String 3",""))`

Comment: Thanks! But let's asume, "String 3" is not always the same content. So e.g. it is "abcde" or "skdjhfkl" or "sldkjhfk". So there is nothing I can actually look for. I only want the 3rd. String. Does that kind of make sense?

Comment: To state it very naively: Give me the String, that is after the second , and in between the "" and put it in a cell.

Comment: Please, provide spreadsheet sample with data and desired result.

Comment: Ok, there you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1whPvGOsQJzpLnstW8YiHUX0XQQlnH8l7S2wJInt4Wy8/edit?usp=sharing

A1:A is the initial data. H1:H is the desired result.

Comment: thanks, now I've updated the answer and the question. Hope, this helps!

Comment: This solves it! Very interesting formula. Never heard of it before. Thanks!